# Compressing multiple consecutive references while using biblatex with chem-acs style loaded

Tags: biblatex

I am currently referencing by using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=chem-acs,sorting=none,biblabel=brackets,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
Somebody told me.\cite{James2003,Allendorf2009,Rowsell2004}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Supposing that the file references.bib contains:

```
@article{James2003,
author = {James, S. L.},
journal = {Chem. Soc. Rev.},
number = {5},
pages = {276--288},
title = {{Metal-organic frameworks}},
volume = {32},
year = {2003}
}

@article{Rowsell2004,
author = {Rowsell, Jesse L.C. and Yaghi, Omar M.},
journal = {Microporous Mesoporous Mater.},
pages = {3--14},
title = {{Metal-organic frameworks: a new class of porous materials}},
volume = {73},
year = {2004}
}

@article{Allendorf2009,
author = {Allendorf, M. D. and Bauer, C. A. and Bhakta, R. K. and Houk, R. J. T.},
journal = {Chem. Soc. Rev.},
number = {5},
pages = {1330--1352},
title = {{Luminescent metal-organic frameworks.}},
volume = {38},
year = {2009}
}
```

Running latex -> biber -> latex -> latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf (need this procedure for other reasons) gives:

```
Somebody told me.[1, 2, 3]
```

How can I get compressed consecutive references like

```
Somebody told me.[1-3]
```

The cite and natbib packages provide compressing but are incompatible with biblatex. biblatex has a numeric-comp style but I need bibliography formatting of chem-acs. The biblatex documentation refers to the sortcites=true option which seems to indeed sort the numbers within the brackets but doesn't provide compressing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just have `\cite{Seo2000,James2003,Davies2010,Allendorf2009,Bureekaew2008,Rowsell2004}`? (`\cites` is for lots of separate citations, for example with notes, whereas `\cite` with a comma-list is several citations 'together'.)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the cites command to cite. Unfortunately it didn't solve the compressing problem at once. Any suggestions concerning that?

Comment: You should get compression 'as standard'. Can you edit-in exactly what you changed, and include some example database entries, so we can test exactly what you are doing?

Comment: I updated the initial post to provide some database entries.

Comment: Which version do you use? I works great with an up to date system.

Comment: There is also the `achemso` package that sets the style and referencing automatically according to ACS guidelines

Comment: @JM That is a `natbib` style, not one for `biblatex`. (I write both, so the two should give very similar results given the correct input for each type of style.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `bibstyle=chem-acs`, which means that the citation style is unchanged from the `biblatex` default. You probably want the `chem-acs` citation style too, which is much easier to do using `style=chem-acs`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{James2003,
author = {James, S. L.},
journal = {Chem. Soc. Rev.},
number = {5},
pages = {276--288},
title = {{Metal-organic frameworks}},
volume = {32},
year = {2003}
}

@article{Rowsell2004,
author = {Rowsell, Jesse L.C. and Yaghi, Omar M.},
journal = {Microporous Mesoporous Mater.},
pages = {3--14},
title = {{Metal-organic frameworks: a new class of porous materials}},
volume = {73},
year = {2004}
}

@article{Allendorf2009,
author = {Allendorf, M. D. and Bauer, C. A. and Bhakta, R. K. and Houk, R. J. T.},
journal = {Chem. Soc. Rev.},
number = {5},
pages = {1330--1352},
title = {{Luminescent metal-organic frameworks.}},
volume = {38},
year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
Somebody told me.\cite{James2003,Allendorf2009,Rowsell2004}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This automatically sets `sorting=none` and `sortcites=true` as that is standard for chemistry styles.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much for your help!